# Is there a way to manually trigger Facebook Meta API's verification webhook manually or check its verification status?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-webhooks

When creating a webhook on the Meta developer platform, one is asked to provide a `Webhook URL` and `verify_token`. Upon clicking `Save & Verify` a verify request is sent to the URL to check whether the endpoint is valid.

The documentation also claims that any changes to the webhook will result in another verification request, which is not the case. So, if one removes the webhook and adds it again, or changes the `verify_token` or `Webhook URL` no additional verify requests are sent to the entered `Webhook URL`.

I am aware that there a subscriptions API that allows checking whether a webhook is active, but it doesn't change to inactive when editing a webhook, since the verification webhook isn't triggering again and therefore cannot fail.

Is it possible to check the status of a webhook via an API call or to manually trigger a verification call from Facebook?